# Java check if one of two variables is null and return the not null variable

Tags: java, null

What is the best way to write something like this in shorthand using operators, if possible?

```
    if (l1 == null && l2 == null){
        return null;
    }
    else if (l1 == null){
        return l2;
    }
    else if (l2 == null){
        return l1;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, it's this:

```java
return l1 == null ? l2 : l1;
```

If l1 & l2 are null, it will return null. Else, if at least one of them it not null, it will return the one that is defined.

Answer (score 0):

For two variables it's probably overkill but a functional way of doing so can be:

```java
return Optional(l1)
  .orElse(l2)
  .getOrElse(null);
```

Self-explanatory I believe.